# What is the difference between len() and sys.getsizeof() methods in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I ran the below code I got 3 and 36 as the answers respectively.

```
x ="abd"
print len(x)
print sys.getsizeof(x)
```

Can someone explain to me what's the difference between them ?

Comment: @moooeeeep: Presumably the OP thought that Python strings are like C strings; one byte per character, plus perhaps a null byte.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. 2 years later the answer was exactly what I was looking for and IMO very relevant to anyone needing to understand string sizes.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

They are not the same thing **at all**.

[`len()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) queries for the number of items contained in a container. For a string that's the number of characters:

> Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may be a sequence (string, tuple or list) or a mapping (dictionary).

[`sys.getsizeof()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) on the other hand returns the **memory size** of the object:

> Return the size of an object in bytes. The object can be any type of object. All built-in objects will return correct results, but this does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is implementation specific.

Python string objects are not simple sequences of characters, 1 byte per character.

Specifically, the `sys.getsizeof()` function includes the garbage collector overhead if any:

> `getsizeof()` calls the object’s `__sizeof__` method and adds an additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed by the garbage collector.

String objects do not need to be tracked (they cannot create circular references), but string objects do need more memory than just the bytes per character. In Python 2, `__sizeof__` method returns (in C code):

```
Py_ssize_t res;
res = PyStringObject_SIZE + PyString_GET_SIZE(v) * Py_TYPE(v)->tp_itemsize;
return PyInt_FromSsize_t(res);
```

where `PyStringObject_SIZE` is the C struct header size for the type, `PyString_GET_SIZE` basically is the same as `len()` and `Py_TYPE(v)->tp_itemsize` is the per-character size. In Python 2.7, for byte strings, the size per character is 1, but it's `PyStringObject_SIZE` that is confusing you; on my Mac that size is 37 bytes:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof('')
37
```

For `unicode` strings the per-character size goes up to 2 or 4 (depending on compilation options). On Python 3.3 and newer, Unicode strings take up between 1 and 4 bytes per character, depending on the *contents* of the string.

For containers such as dictionaries or lists that reference other objects, the memory size given covers *only* the memory used by the container and the pointer values used to reference those other objects. There is no straightforward method of including the memory size of the ‘contained’ objects because those same objects could have many more references elsewhere and are not necessarily owned by a single container.

The documentation states it like this:

> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.

If you need to calculate the memory footprint of a container and anything referenced by that container you’ll have to use some method of traversing to those contained objects and get their size; the documentation points to a [recursive recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/).

Answer (score 1):

key difference is that len() will give **actual length** of elements in container , Whereas sys.getsizeof() will give it's **memory size** which it occupy

for more information read docs of python which is available at
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#module-sys