# How much memory does this byte string actually take up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, encoding, base64

My understanding is that os.urandom(size) outputs a random string of bytes of the given "size", but then:

```
import os
import sys

print(sys.getsizeof(os.urandom(42)))

>>>
75
```

Why is this not 42?

And a related question:

```
import base64
import binascii


print(sys.getsizeof(base64.b64encode(os.urandom(42))))
print(sys.getsizeof(binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(42))))

>>>
89
117
```

Why are these so different? Which encoding would be the most memory efficient way to store a string of bytes such as that given by os.urandom?

Edit: It seems like quite a stretch to say that this question is a duplicate of [What is the difference between len() and sys.getsizeof() methods in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574076/what-is-the-difference-between-len-and-sys-getsizeof-methods-in-python) My question is not about the difference between len() and getsizeof(). I was confused about the memory used by Python objects in general, which the answer to this question has clarified for me.

Comment: In your second example the resulting strings are different length (base64 vs. hex), therefore are not equal. You can usually figure out how much memory each object uses by taking the result of `getsizeof()` and subtract the `len()` of each object, so in your case each object has 33 extra bytes added onto to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python byte string objects are more than just the characters that comprise them. They are fully fledged objects. As such they require more space to accommodate the object's components such as the type pointer (needed to identify what kind of object the bytestring even is) and the length (needed for efficiency and because Python bytestrings can contain null bytes).

The simplest object, an `object` instance, requires space:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(object())
16
```

The second part of your question is simply because the strings produced by `b64encode()` and `hexlify()` have different lengths; the latter being 28 characters longer which, unsurprisingly, is the difference in the values reported by `sys.getsizeof()`.

```
>>> s1 = base64.b64encode(os.urandom(42))
>>> s1
b'CtlMjDM9q7zp+pGogQci8gr0igJsyZVjSP4oWmMj2A8diawJctV/8sTa'
>>> s2 = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(42))
>>> s2
b'c82d35f717507d6f5ffc5eda1ee1bfd50a62689c08ba12055a5c39f95b93292ddf4544751fbc79564345'

>>> len(s2) - len(s1)
28
>>> sys.getsizeof(s2) - sys.getsizeof(s1)
28
```

---

Unless you use some form of compression, there is no encoding that will be more efficient than the binary string that you already have, and this is particularly true in this case because the data is *random* which is inherently incompressible.