# Why the size of numpy array is different?

Tags: numpy

I have two numpy `a,b` the shape of them are (100,2048), and I used `sys.getsizeof(a) = 112` and same with array b.

I have question, when I use `c = np.concatenate((a,b),axis=0)`, the shape of c is (200,2048), but the `sys.getsizeof(c) = 1638512`

Why?

Comment: Could you include the code you use? I can't reproduce your example

Answer (score 1):

`getsizeof` has limited value.  It can be way off for lists.  For arrays it's better, but you have to understand how arrays are stored.

```
In [447]: import sys
In [448]: a = np.arange(100)
In [449]: sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[449]: 896
```

But look at the `size` of a `view`:

```
In [450]: b = a.reshape(10,10)
In [451]: sys.getsizeof(b)
Out[451]: 112
```

This shows the size of the array object, but not the size of the shared databuffer.  `b` doesn't have its own databuffer.

```
In [453]: a.size
Out[453]: 100
In [454]: b.size
Out[454]: 100
```

So my guess is that your `a` and `b` are views of some other arrays.  But the concatenate produces a new array with its own databuffer.  It can't be a view of the other two.  So its `getsizeof` reflects that.

```
In [457]: c = np.concatenate((a,b.ravel()))
In [459]: c.shape
Out[459]: (200,)
In [460]: c.size
Out[460]: 200
In [461]: sys.getsizeof(c)
Out[461]: 1696
```

The databuffer for `a` is 100*8 bytes, so the 'overhead' is 96.  For `c`, 200*8, again with a 96 'overhead'.

Answer (score 0):

It do not reproduce your example:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

a = np.random.rand(100, 2048)
b = np.random.rand(100, 2048)

print(sys.getsizeof(a), sys.getsizeof(b))
# 1638512 1638512

c = np.concatenate((a,b), axis=0)
print(sys.getsizeof(c))
# 3276912   which is about 1638512 + 1638512
```

Comment: Thx, the code I used is from some one else, see:https://github.com/Maluuba/gensen. It's a sentence embedding, which can convert a string (sentence) into a 2048 dimension vector, so every 100 sentences have a (100,2048) vector. I also confused why the size of a is only 112, maybe they used some compress technique that I don't know. anyway, I convert to list and then convert back to numpy array it's normal, thanks.

Comment: here is some detail about `getsizeof` https://stackoverflow.com/a/17574104/8069403 , maybe it could help understand what happens