# Time series data preprocessing - numpy strides trick to save memory

Tags: python, numpy, data-structures, time-series

I am preprocessing a timeseries dataset changing its shape from 2-dimensions (datapoints, features) into a 3-dimensions (datapoints, time_window, features).

In such perspective time windows (sometimes also called look back) indicates the number of previous time steps/datapoints that are involved as input variables to predict the next time period. In other words time windows is how much data in past the machine learning algorithm takes into consideration for a single prediction in the future.

The issue with such approach (or at least with my implementation) is that it is quite inefficient in terms of memory usage since it brings data redundancy across the windows causing the input data to become very heavy.

This is the function that I have been using so far to reshape the input data into a 3 dimensional structure.

```
from sys import getsizeof

def time_framer(data_to_frame, window_size=1):
    """It transforms a 2d dataset into 3d based on a specific size;
    original function can be found at:
    https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/
    """
    n_datapoints = data_to_frame.shape[0] - window_size
    framed_data = np.empty(
        shape=(n_datapoints, window_size, data_to_frame.shape[1],)).astype(np.float32)

    for index in range(n_datapoints):
        framed_data[index] = data_to_frame[index:(index + window_size)]
        print(framed_data.shape)

    # it prints the size of the output in MB
    print(framed_data.nbytes / 10 ** 6)
    print(getsizeof(framed_data) / 10 ** 6)

    # quick and dirty quality test to check if the data has been correctly reshaped        
    test1=list(set(framed_data[0][1]==framed_data[1][0]))
    if test1[0] and len(test1)==1:
        print('Data is correctly framed')

    return framed_data
```

I have been suggested to use [numpy's strides trick](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided) to overcome such problem and reduce the size of the reshaped data. Unfortunately, any resource I found so far on this subject is focused on implementing the trick on a 2 dimensional array, just as this [excellent tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XijN-pjOz-A). I have been struggling with my use case which involves a 3 dimensional output. Here is the best I came out with; however, it neither succeeds in reducing the size of the framed_data, nor it frames the data correctly as it does not pass the quality test.

I am quite sure that my error is on the *strides* parameter which I did not fully understood. The *new_strides* are the only values I managed to successfully feed to *as_strided*.

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def strides_trick_time_framer(data_to_frame, window_size=1):

    new_strides = (data_to_frame.strides[0],
                   data_to_frame.strides[0]*data_to_frame.shape[1] ,
                   data_to_frame.strides[0]*window_size)

    n_datapoints = data_to_frame.shape[0] - window_size
    print('striding.....')
    framed_data = as_strided(data_to_frame, 
                             shape=(n_datapoints, # .flatten() here did not change the outcome
                                    window_size,
                                    data_to_frame.shape[1]),                   
                                    strides=new_strides).astype(np.float32)
    # it prints the size of the output in MB
    print(framed_data.nbytes / 10 ** 6)
    print(getsizeof(framed_data) / 10 ** 6)

    # quick and dirty test to check if the data has been correctly reshaped        
    test1=list(set(framed_data[0][1]==framed_data[1][0]))
    if test1[0] and len(test1)==1:
        print('Data is correctly framed')

    return framed_data
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I edited the question since I actually convert to float32 in order to save space. I dont know if it changes anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this `X`:

```
In [734]: X = np.arange(24).reshape(8,3)
In [735]: X.strides
Out[735]: (24, 8)
```

this `as_strided` produces the same array as your `time_framer`

```
In [736]: np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(X, 
            shape=(X.shape[0]-3, 3, X.shape[1]), 
            strides=(24, 24, 8))
Out[736]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20]]])
```

It strides the last dimension just like `X`.  And 2nd to the last as well.  The first advances one row, so it too gets `X.strides[0]`.  So the window size only affects the shape, not the strides.

So in your `as_strided` version just use:

```
 new_strides = (data_to_frame.strides[0],
                data_to_frame.strides[0] ,
                data_to_frame.strides[1])
```

---

Minor corrections.  Set the default window size to 2 or larger.  1 produces an indexing error in the test.

```
framed_data[0,1]==framed_data[1,0]
```

---

Looking a `getsizeof`:

```
In [754]: sys.getsizeof(X)
Out[754]: 112
In [755]: X.nbytes
Out[755]: 192
```

Wait, why is `X` size smaller than `nbytes`?  Because it is a `view` (see line [734] above).

```
In [756]: sys.getsizeof(X.copy())
Out[756]: 304
```

As noted in another SO, `getsizeof` has to be used with caution:

[Why the size of numpy array is different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129595/why-the-size-of-numpy-array-is-different)

Now for the expanded copy:

```
In [757]: x2=time_framer(X,4)
...
In [758]: x2.strides
Out[758]: (96, 24, 8)
In [759]: x2.nbytes
Out[759]: 384
In [760]: sys.getsizeof(x2)
Out[760]: 512
```

and the strided version

```
In [761]: x1=strides_trick_time_framer(X,4)
...
In [762]: x1.strides
Out[762]: (24, 24, 8)
In [763]: sys.getsizeof(x1)
Out[763]: 128
In [764]: x1.astype(int).strides
Out[764]: (96, 24, 8)
In [765]: sys.getsizeof(x1.astype(int))
Out[765]: 512
```

`x1` size is just like a view (128 because its 3d).  But if we try to change its `dtype`, it makes a copy, and the strides and size are the same as `x2`.

Many operations on `x1` will loose the strided size advantage, `x1.ravel()`, `x1+1` etc.  It's mainly reduction operations like `mean` and `sum` that produce a real space savings.

Comment: by using `sys.getsizeof` I see the improvements but  as I edited I actually convert dtype to float32 in order to save memory; as float 32 the "strided" array does not become any lighter

Comment: The `as_strided` array is a `view` of the original.  That is, it uses the original's databuffer.  The `astype` forces it to make a copy, and it will be full one.  Compare the `strides` attribute with and without the `astype`.  There are a limited number of things you can do with an `as_strided` array before it creates a full blown copy.

Comment: I added some `getsizeof` tests.

Comment: so, `getsizeof` is not useful for the a view - which is what the strides trick returns;`astype` on a view creates a copy of the original - neutralizing the benefit of the strides trick; @Daniel F pointed out that `nbytes` is a naive `ndarray.itemsize * ndarray.size`that doesn't take into account shared elements;

Comment: Right there isn't a meaningful measure of the memory savings with `as_strided`.  As a view it doesn't take any extra memory (other than the array object overhead), and a copy is expanded to full size.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the stride template function `window_nd` I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960192/using-numpy-as-strided-function-to-create-patches-tiles-rolling-or-sliding-w/45960193#45960193)

Then to stride over just the first dimension you just need

```
framed_data = window_nd(data_to_frame, window_size, axis = 0)
```

Haven't found a built-in window function yet that can work over arbitrary axes, so unless there's been a new one implemented in `scipy.signal` or `skimage` recently, that's probably your best bet.

**EDIT:** To see the memory savings, you will need to use the method described by @ali_m [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637875/size-of-numpy-strided-array-broadcast-array-in-memory) as the basic `ndarray.nbytes` is naive to shared memory.

```
def find_base_nbytes(obj):
    if obj.base is not None:
        return find_base_nbytes(obj.base)
    return obj.nbytes
```

Comment: the new array passes the quality check, but the size in terms of memory did not improve

Comment: Huh.  `ndarray.nbytes` seems to be a naive `ndarray.itemsize * ndarray.size`.  It doesn't take into acount shared elements at all.  If you want to determine the actal size of the strided array, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637875/size-of-numpy-strided-array-broadcast-array-in-memory) for a method.

Comment: I see the memory improvement only if I use `sys.getsizeof` (no improvement with base attribute) and only if I keep the dtype as float64. if I use float32 in order to save some more memory the resulting array does not have the base attribute and does not improve in terms of memory

Comment: Be careful when using `getsizeof` with arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129595/why-the-size-of-numpy-array-is-different