# what is the need to divide a list sys.getsizeof() by 8 or 4 ( Depending upon the machine) after subtracting 64 or 36 from the list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find the capacity of a list by a function. But a step involves subtracting the list size by 64 ( in my machine ) and also it has to be divided by 8 to get the capacity. What does this capacity value mean ?

I tried reading the docs of python to know about sys.getsizeof() method but still it couldn't answer my doubts.

```
import sys
def disp(l1):
    print("Capacity",(sys.getsizeof(l1)-64)//8)    // What does this line mean especially //8 part 

    print("Length",len(l1))

mariya_list=[]
mariya_list.append("Sugarisverysweetand it can be used for cooking sweets 
and also used in beverages ")
mariya_list.append("Choco")
mariya_list.append("bike")

disp(mariya_list)
print(mariya_list)
mariya_list.append("lemon")
print(mariya_list)
disp(mariya_list)
mariya_list.insert(1,"leomon Tea")
print(mariya_list)
disp(mariya_list)
```

Output:
Capacity 4
Length 1
['Choco']
['Choco', 'lemon']
Capacity 4
Length 2
['Choco', 'leomon Tea', 'lemon']
Capacity 4
Length 3

## This is the output. Here I am unable to understand what does capacity 4 mean. Why does it repeats the same value four even after subsequent addition of elements.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574076/what-is-the-difference-between-len-and-sys-getsizeof-methods-in-python)? It explains the relationship between sizeof and length pretty well, even though it uses strings as an example, unlike your code. Also, I notice that you seem to be struggling with the meaning of "capacity" even though that's a word you brought in voluntarily (it isn't used in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof)). What do you *intend* it to mean?

Comment: Yeah Hi wumpus. The word capacity is that how many items it can accommodate. But my doubt exactly is whether the 4 is size of a string in that list or something else. Since it is a 64 bit machine I had to divide the size by 8. That's why I couldn't get why 4 comes as output.