# condition to check if the list include a string except the string that I want

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I want to write a condition that check if the list has another string that is not `'1'` or `'2'`.
For example:

```
list = ['1', '2'] -> is True
list = ['1', '3'] -> is false
```

I tried something like that but it didn't work:

```
if list[0] is not '1' or list[0] is not '2' and list[1] is not '1' or list[1] is not '2':
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Help someone??

Answer (score 2):

Use `all` in a generator:

```
def check_value(lst):
    return all(x in ('1', '2') for x in lst)
```

**Usage**:

```
>>> check_value(['1', '2'])
True
>>> check_value(['1', '3'])
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any()` for this, simply pythonic:

```py
def check_list(l):
    return not any(x not in ('1', '2') for x in l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `list` as variable since it is a built-in function.

```
checking_elements = ['1', '2']

ls = ['1', '3']

for ele in ls:
    if ele not in checking_elements:
        return False

return True
```

if your `ls` is going to be only two elements.Then

```
checking_elements = ['1', '2']

ls = ['1', '3']

return (ls[0] in checking_elements and ls[1] in checking_elements)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hellooooo!!
First thing u can do is to make an iter object.

```
s=iter("12")
```

This will create an iter object with "1" and "2".You must be thinking why to use iter rather than a list.
The answer lies in the size,memory of iter objects is less than that of list.

```
import sys
l=["1","2"]
s=iter("12")
sys.getsizeof(l)  #return 72
sys.getsizeof(s)  #return 48
```

So what i did was that,i got the memory size of l and s.
If you want to know more about this function,then go to [sys.getsizof()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574076/what-is-the-difference-between-len-and-sys-getsizeof-methods-in-python)
Now coming back to your question,check the code below.

```
for element in l:
    if element in s:
       print("69 is not just a number!!!")    #You can replace this part by anything u want
```

Output:

```
69 is not just a number!!!
69 is not just a number!!!
```

The benefit of this is that you can use this for much more strings!!!.And the memory will be very less.

You can also do it how **Austin** did it.

Keep Learning!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, welcome! :)

We can try the all() function to check all the elements in the list using if statements (making it a little easier to read):

For example:

```
list1 = ['1', '3']

if all(elem in ('1', '2') for elem in list1): #if all elements in the list have '1' or '2'
    True     #return true

else:        #if not
    False    #return false
```

Output:

```
False
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this,

```
l1=['1','2']
l2=['1','3']
def check(l1):
    if '1' in l1 and '2' in l1:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')

check(l1)
check(l2)
```

output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: but l = ['1', '2'] is also should be True.

Comment: The list should include either '1' or '2', every other character is False

Comment: It is still wrong, run your code on `['1', '2', '3']`